# How to better handle player movement in a canvas game?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a side scrolling space ship game and I've been trying to find a way to efficiently handle player movement. This has been my code so far that I've copied from sources:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);

setInterval(move, 33.3);

keys = {};

function keyDown(event){
    keys[event.keyCode] = true;
}

function keyUp(event){
    delete keys[event.keyCode];
}

function move(){
    if (65 in keys && player.x > 0)
        player.x -=5;
    if (68 in keys && player.x < 576)
        player.x +=5;
    if (87 in keys && player.y > 0)
        player.y -= 5;
    if (83 in keys && player.y < 576)
        player.y += 5;

}
```

**Questions**:

1. Why do I need to set `keys[event.keyCode]` as *true*? What does this statement do?
2. Does `delete keys[event.keyCode]` just delete any property that contains that keyCode in the key object?
3. What would be a better way to implement player movement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I need to set `keys[event.keyCode]` as true? What does this statement do?

Technically, you don't. You just need to add *some value* at `keys[event.keyCode]`. What that's doing is adding a key to your `keys` object that matches the key code. That allows you to check later and see if the player has pressed that button. You could also add the value to an array or something similar. This just provides an easy way of looking up if a given key has been pressed.

> Does `delete keys[event.keyCode]` just delete any property that contains that keyCode in the key object?

It deletes the `event.keyCode` property from the `keys` object. For example, imagine the player had previously pressed "A" or key code 65. `delete keys[event.keyCode]` is equivalent to `delete keys[65]`. Now the `keys` object no longer has a `65` property and won't return `true` when you check for it in `move`.

> What would be a better way to implement player movement?

What you have done is perfectly reasonable and used in a number of games. In fact, it's the technique that I used when I [wrote a game engine.](https://github.com/MCluck90/psykick2d)

Comment: So just to be sure, the keys object will always only have a ONE property with the (say 65) keycode right?

Comment: @PixelProgrammer Not necessarily. If the user presses, for example, two keys at once then `keys` will have two properties; one for each key. That's another reason why this is a good solution. It allows you to easily handle multiple button presses at once.

Comment: Of course, but it would only have one property with that keyCode. So one property with 65, one with 68. The reason I asked was because if I were to use arrays, it would mean that the array might hold multiple keyCodes and I wanted to make sure that was not the case with Objects.

Comment: Both `keyCode` and `charCode` are depreciated properties of the keyboard event object, and you should avoid using them. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode Use `keyboardEvent.code` and set `keys = {}` rather than an array. Then set in the handler with `keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";` then you can read the state with `if(keys.ArrowUp){...` which is much easier to remember and makes the code more readable. `event.code` is the key name eg `KeyW` and `event.key` is the intended key eg `W` or `w` depending on shift.

Comment: @Blindman67 Oh wow, I didn't even know about `event.code`. That's awesome. Thanks for that.